# Utilizar fechas

Tags: java, date, parsear

He empezado a estudiar Java. Estoy liado con un ejercicio y hay algunos conceptos que no veo. Me explico. Por ejemplo una clase `Alumno` con atributos `nombre` y `fechaDeNacimiento`. ¿Cómo tratar esta fecha en esta clase?, donde el constructor tenga esos argumentos y tratar la fecha `String` a `Date` mediante `parse` y asignar el resultado a `fechaDeNacimiento`. Es decir, con el constructor convertir texto a fecha (con `parse` y `format`) y utilizar un método `toString` para convertir fecha a texto.

Gracias de antemano.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Alumno {
    
    //Declarar atributos
        protected String nombre;
        protected Date fechaDeNacimiento;
        
        // Constructor con parametros
        public Alumno(String nombre, Date fechaDeNacimiento) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.fechaDeNacimiento = fechaDeNacimiento;

        }
        
        //Getters y Setters
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        
        public Date getFechaDeNacimiento() {
            return fechaDeNacimiento;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Alumno [nombre=" + nombre + ", fechaDeNacimiento=" + fechaDeNacimiento + "]";
        }   
        
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. No sé cuál sea específicamente el problema pues la descripción es más o menos clara: Hay que crear un constructor que reciba un string y parsearlo a Date con [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) o simplemente con el constructor de [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Te recomiendo leer [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException


public class Alumno {
    
    // Atributos de Alumno
    private String nombre;
    private Date fechaNacimiento;
    
    
    // Constructor con parametros
    public Alumno (String nombre, String fechaNacimiento) throws ParseException {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fechaNacimiento = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(fechaNacimiento);
                }
   
    // Getters
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public String getFechaNacimiento() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").format(fechaNacimiento);
        }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  nombre + fechaNacimiento;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta?